# Custom UIView transitions

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I am implementing a slide show which will change images using custom animations. http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo1 This is link of transitions. Is it possible to implement these 17 transitions using UIKit and CoreAnimations or I have to use something of my own.

Core animations provides animations like these

```
animationsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cameraIris",@"cube",@"fade",
    @"moveIn",@"oglFlip",@"pageCurl",@"pageUnCurl",@"push",@"reveal",@"rippleEffect",
    @"suckEffect",@"genieEffect",@"oglFlip, fromLeft",@"oglFlip, fromRight",
    @"spewEffect",@"cameraIrisHollowClose",@"cameraIrisHollowOpen",@"unGenieEffect",
    @"twist",@"tubey",@"swirl",@"charminUltra",@"zoomyIn",@"zoomyOut",
    @"oglApplicationSuspend",@"reflection",@"mapCurl",@"mapUnCurl", nil];
```

Is there any way to create custom animations like these in the array ?

Comment: iOS by default does not provide the animations shown in the link. You can search if there are any third-party libraries providing this or implement it on your own.

Comment: Thanks @Adithya I have searched a lot and so far no help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a big project depending on how complex your animations will be.  I'd recommend looking into [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), and if that doesn't do what you need, you may have to use [Open GL](https://developer.apple.com/opengl-es/).

Comment: Thanks WolfLink. I have looked into the Core Animation. Maybe I have to implement it by using a mixture of both.